# API Reference building locally but not on RTD

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to build an API reference for the Python Package [GemGIS](https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis) using `autosummary` ([see here](https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis/blob/dev_gemgis3/docs/getting_started/api.rst)).

The API Reference is built locally without any issues but I am getting `ImportError`s and `ModuleNotFoundError`s saying that various GemGIS modules are missing. [Here is the link](https://readthedocs.org/projects/gemgis/builds/21532155/) to the latest build on RTD.

```
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: getting_started/about.rst, getting_started/api.rst, getting_started/authors.rst, getting_started/contributing.rst, getting_started/data_types.ipynb, getting_started/example/example01.ipynb, getting_started/example/example02.ipynb, getting_started/example/example03.ipynb, getting_started/example/example04.ipynb, getting_started/example/example05.ipynb, ..., getting_started/tutorial/66_generating_voronoi_polygons.ipynb, getting_started/tutorial/67_rotating_gempy_input_data.ipynb, getting_started/tutorial/index.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/index.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/interpolations.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/mesh.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/projections.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/raster.rst, getting_started/whatiswhat/vector.rst, index.rst
WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import gemgis.raster.calculate_aspect.
Possible hints:
* KeyError: 'gemgis'
* ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gemgis.vector'; 'gemgis' is not a package
* ImportError: no module named gemgis.raster
```

The `conf.py` with links to the respective directory is [here](https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis/blob/dev_gemgis3/docs/conf.py) and should be working as the API Reference builds locally.

I am using different environments for the local build and the one on RTD. The one for RTD can be found [here](https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis/blob/dev_gemgis3/environment_dev.yml) and should, by now, include all the packages needed for GemGIS (there are a couple of optional dependencies). I noticed that the error message on RTD changes when installing optional dependencies. However, the error messages are not helpful to me at that point anymore and I do not know which other packages could be missing.

Excluding GemGIS using `autodoc_mock_imports = ["gemgis"]` builds the autosummary on RTD but not the different HTML pages for the different methods.

What I have tried so far:

- Checked that the API Reference builds locally and then pushed it to GitHub.
- Added optional dependencies to the `environment_dev.yml` to mitigate the `ImportError` and `ModuleNotFoundError`.
- Added paths to the `conf.py` file so that RTD finds the modules
- Excluded gemgis from the docs

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add an `install` sub-key under the `python` key in your `.readthedocs.yaml` config, as shown here:
https://www.zonca.dev/posts/2020-05-27-readthedocs-conda.html

So starting from line 20 of your [.readthedocs.yaml](https://github.com/cgre-aachen/gemgis/blob/b4a1a351209da0f3db7c73d3403bb303c6b105c5/.readthedocs.yaml#L20C1-L21C16), it should read

```yaml
python:
   version: 3.8
   install:
      - method: pip
        path: .
```

That way RTD will actually `pip install gemgis` into your conda environment, and fix those `ImportError`s.

See a description of the `install` sub-key in the readthedocs docs here, for more info: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/index.html#adjust-python-configuration